# Ping programmatically on Windows CE 5 with .NET Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, windows-ce, ping

I already tried a few methods, that are available on the internet, but it seems like no one found a solution to ping something using c# on Windows CE 5 with .NET Framework 3.5. There is no way, that I can use any other version than CE 5 and I also cant use .NET Framework 4 or higher. With one of these cases, there were solutions to this.

If no one of you know some small solution to this, may anyone help me understanding how to do that on my own? There are only a few threads which cover how to program that on our own and none of them are easy to understand.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You should give us what are these other approaches that didn't work for you

Comment: Sorry for the title and thanks for editing it. There are Ping classes or even Librarys, that you can use to solve this problem. An example is OpenNETCF, which is not supported here.

Comment: Have you tried executing cmds from C#? Also have you looked at [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883419.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms883419.aspx)

Comment: That is exactly what I was trying after posting this question. I couldn't find a solution to read the console properly to fetch ping.exe output.